# Shell script to get all files from S3 bucket

Tags: shell, amazon-s3

I want to write a shell script for getting all the files which are present in my S3 bucket. Can someone help me with that.

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "getting all the files" you mean downloading all the files, then just call AWS CLI's `s3 cp` command with `--recursive` option.

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 cp s3://some-bucket some-local-path/ --recursive
```

If you need just a list of object, do the same with `ls` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 ls s3://some-bucket --recursive
```

Documentation:

- https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html
- https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

Comment: Not through AWS CLI. I just want to create shell script that will get me all the files from S3 and this shell script i want to keep in my github repo.

Comment: @007_programmer The shell script can use the AWS CLI. Alternatively, you can write a script in Python that does a similar job (but it needs the boto3 Python library loaded).